# Abusive or Disallowed Content

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0

I recently started receiving error below.

"The action attempted has been deemed abusive or is otherwise disallowed", OAuthException #368

I am using same methods and triggers in other apps too but somehow this app is blocked as spam or there is another problem. I have read [this](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/11372890/oauthexception-368-the-action-attempted-has-been-deemed-abusive-or-is-otherwi) link but couldn't find a solution. If I need to contact Facebook to resolve this issue, how should I contact to them? We haven't received developer alert too for this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's likely nothing wrong with your app.

The message refers specifically the content being posted, some attribute of that content (e.g. the image or domain of the action links) or the combination of user posting it, destination, and content.

Something you're trying to post has been marked as spam, probably. Trying to post the same content in Facebook's own interface should give an error message with a link to flag it as a false positive

Comment: Igy, Regarding your answer, what can I do in order to fix it?

Comment: Trying to post the same content in Facebook's own interface should give an error message with a link to flag it as a false positive

Comment: How can I post the apprequests and publish_streams in Facebook's own interface?

Comment: I cannot post my app's domain on normal facebook messaging interface. If domain is blocked, why can't I send normal apprequests via JS api. Those calls do not contain any url containing my domain.

Comment: Is it your app's callback domain which is blocked? if so, that's pribably it

Comment: Yes, it is blocked but I don't know how I can fix it. There is no contact information. I reported several times but no return came yet.

Comment: Then the quickest fix is to use another domain

Comment: Thanks Igy for all your help.